# Show children resources beneath parent resource in fullcalendar vertical resource view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Is it possible to get the vertical resource view in fullcalendar to show child resources underneath the parent resource?

I currently get this:
[image: Current View]

But would like something more like this:
[image]

It's very much like this [4-day resource view example](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-custom-demo), except instead of the Resource as the parent and dates underneath, it would be Resource as the parent and children resources underneath.

Comment: As far as I know that isn't possible currently. You'd be better to submit a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to fullCalendar than ask a question here, I think